# Is 'there was life beyond Earth' a subjunctive clause?

Tags: meaning, subjunctives

> People have always wondered if **there was life** beyond Earth. Technology caught up with their curiosity in 1957 with the Soviet Union's launch
> of the space satellite *Sputnik 1*. Then in 1958, the National
> Aeronautics and Space Administration (NASA) launched its first
> satellite Explorer 1. During the 1960s, unpiloted space craft
> photographed and surveyed the Moon.

Does "there was life" mean the past or a subjunctive usage?

Comment: Compare to *People often wonder if there **is** life beyond Earth*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the sentence just has a mistake.
I think the auther tried to adjust tenses.
You can say:
People wondered if there was life beyond Earth.(past + past)
This means that people had a question "Is there any life beyond Earth?" in the past.

You can also say:
People have wondered if there is life beyond Earth.(present past + present)
This means that people have had a question "Is there any life beyond Earth?" from the past until now.

If you write "People have wonderd if there was life beyond Earth," that would mean this:
People have had a questiion "Was there any life beyond Earth?"

Please tell me if I am not correct.  I am not a native speaker.  I will delete my answer then.